# Calculate date column with Shareponit 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I need a column to calculate the difference of days with the previous record of the same column.
it's possible?

[image]

Comment: with what would you compare if you have only one column? are you able to use SharePoint designer? did you consider workflow on edit to copy column's old value and put it in workflow variable or in a new list column and than to calculate the difference between old and new values?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible with calculated field. because calculate field considered only fields in current item when executing formula.

Alternate way which I can think of is
Create a workflow to update this column. Every time item is added you can get Last Item and read date column of last item.
Calculate the difference between dates and update in separate column say "Days".